# Spark: add two columns and fill them with data computed from other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

Using pyspark 2.0.1

I have this data frame

```
+-----------+----------+
| Longitude | Latitude |
+-----------+----------+
|  1        |  3       |
|  2        |  1       |
|  2        |  3       |
+-----------+----------+
```

I would like to efficiently add two columns called City, Province that for every row, use the values of columns (Longitude and Latitude) as input to a python function that I already wrote that return the city and Province.
So the output should look like this

```
    +-----------+----------+--------+--------
    | Longitude | Latitude | City  | Province
    +-----------+----------+--------+--------
    |  1        |  3       | London| London
    |  2        |  1       | Paris | Paris
    |  2        |  3       | Dubai | Dubai
    +-----------+----------+--------+--------
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

def city(lat, long): your code
def province(lat, long): your code

cityUdf = udf(city, StringType())
provinceUdf = udf(province, StringType())

df2 = df.withColumn("city", cityUdf(df["Latitude"], df["Longitude"]))
df3 = df2.withColumn("province", provinceUdf(df2["Latitude"], df2["Longitude"]))
```